# Sacar diferencia de fechas con javascript

Tags: javascript, date

espero me puedan ayudar a revisar el script de mi código, ya que quiero que al escribir la fecha de inicio y de final me de la cantidad de días trabajados, pero no me imprime nada.
[base a este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287819/sumar-d%C3%ADas-a-fecha-y-generar-la-nueva-fecha-en-un-input-text)[referencia 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150867/c%C3%B3mo-limitar-el-resultado-de-la-suma-de-dos-fechas-dependiendo-de-un-n%C3%BAmero-est)

Gracias.

```js
function dif() {
  var fechaI = new Date(document.getElementById("FechaI").value);
  var fechaF = new Date(document.getElementById("FechaFin").value);
  var tiempo = fechaF.getTime() - fechaI.getTime();
  console.log(fechaI);
  var dias = Math.floor(tiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  document.getElementById("Tiempo").innerHTML = dias;
  document.getElementById("Tiempo").value = dias;

};
```

```html
<input type="Date" onchange="dif()" onblur="dif()" id="FechaI" name="FechaInicio" data-inputmask="'alias': 'yyyy/MM/dd'" data-mask required/>
<input type="Date" onchange="dif()" onblur="dif()" id="FechaFin" name="FechaFin" data-inputmask="'alias': 'yyyy/mm/dd'" />
 <input id="Tiempo" name="Tiempo" value="" >
```

Answer (score 1):

No utilices ***innerHTML*** sino ***value***, así:

```
  document.getElementById("Tiempo").value = dias;
```

[Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609130/set-the-value-of-an-input-field) también dan respuesta a tu pregunta.

```js
function dif() {
  var fechaI = new Date(document.getElementById("FechaI").value);
  var fechaF = new Date(document.getElementById("FechaFin").value);
  var tiempo = fechaF.getTime() - fechaI.getTime();
  console.log(fechaI);
  var dias = Math.floor(tiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  document.getElementById("Tiempo").value = dias;

};
```

```html
<input type="Date" onchange="dif()" onblur="dif()" id="FechaI" name="FechaInicio" data-inputmask="'alias': 'yyyy/MM/dd'" data-mask required/>
<input type="Date" onchange="dif()" onblur="dif()" id="FechaFin" name="FechaFin" data-inputmask="'alias': 'yyyy/mm/dd'" />
 <input id="Tiempo" name="Tiempo" value="" >
```

Comment: ya lo cambie y no

Comment: Modifiqué tu código, funciona. Ejecuta el snipet de arriba porfa.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

parece que tu pregunta se respondio aqui.

```
const date1 = new Date('7/13/2010');
const date2 = new Date('12/15/2010');
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

Solo valida que este llegando correctamente los datos de tus campos inputs

Comment: no es precisamente lo que necesito ya que yo quiero que me lo mande en otro input

Comment: Solo para no descartar recuerdo que una vez me sucedia que no podia ponerle valor a un elemento disabled, puede ponerselo de nuevo luego de que le asignes el valor.

Comment: ya quite el disabled y no mando nada